# Start event after TouchEnd ends

Tags: javascript, jquery, events

Basically I have this this mobile menu [Link](http://tarprodemo9.asphaltthemes.com/) ( please resize the window to see mobile menu). The problem is that on mobile, users usually swipe down to see the content. Main menu on mobile.  Any way to activate the "click" of the menu, upon release of the finger - instead of upon first touch?  The issue is that if you're scrolling and happen to tap "menu", it opens the menu instead of scrolls.  All other links on the page are fine - they only "click" when you release your finger on it (instead of first touch). So if users accidentally touch on "Menu" button, the menu opens. I want show the menu ONLY after user touch and release the menu button. To do that I'm using this code -

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
  if (window.Touch) {
    jQuery('#sidr').bind('touchstart', function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
    });
    jQuery('#sidr').bind('touchend', function(e) {
      jQuery(this).trigger('click');
    });
  }
});
```

But it's not working, any suggestions ?

I just noticed the preventDefault is not working

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
jQuery('#sidr').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
  })
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using the jQueryMobile [tap handler](https://api.jquerymobile.com/tap/). It will only fire after a completed touch event (i.e. on "touchend"). You can be even more restrictive and use the [taphold handler](https://api.jquerymobile.com/taphold/), which is essentially a long touch.

Comment: Tried both of this combination - https://hastebin.com/dipemijuyo.js still couldn't make it work. Sorry I'm amateur when it comes to JS

Comment: the best way to get better is to read code and documentation, I know it's boring as hell but it works. You shouldn't be using .bind, you should be using .on all you need is $(element).on('tap', function)

Comment: Thank you, will try again with you suggestion